# java/jsp How to reverse result set?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm coding a wall, and i would like to show all the contents to that wall(Comments and posts etc. Like facebook's wall)

I'm using jsp to print out html content containing the comments and posts.

```
ResultSet wallrs = dbconnect.getWallResultset();
    if(wallrs!=null){
        while(wallrs.next()){
            %>
            <br><b><%=wallrs.getString("navn")%></b>
            <div style="max-width: 500px;"><br><%=wallrs.getString("besked") %></div>
            <%

            wallrsid = wallrs.getInt("id");
            ResultSet kommentarrs = dbconnect.getKommentarResultset(wallrsid);

            if(kommentarrs!=null){
                while(kommentarrs.next()){
                    %>
                    <Blockquote><b><%=kommentarrs.getString("navn") %>:</b> <%=kommentarrs.getString("kommentar") %></Blockquote>
                    <%
                }
            }
            if(dbconnect.loggedIn){
            %>
            <form id="<%= wallrsid%>"></form>
            <button onclick="show_form('<%= wallrsid%>')">Kommenter</button>
            <%
            }
        }
        String message = request.getParameter("kommentar");
        if(message!=null){
            dbconnect.createComment(message, request.getRemoteAddr(), wallrsid);
            System.out.println("Message: " + message + " Ip adresse: " + request.getRemoteAddr() + " Besked id: " + wallrsid);
            message = null;
        }
    }
    dbconnect.cleanUp();
```

This is what i'm dealing with. It prints it out, so the new comments get's in the bottom instead of in the top.

How do i make it reverse ?

I know i could loop the resultset over to an arraylist, and loop the arraylist "backwards" But that seems like an resource consuming way, and i thought there might be a better way :)

Answer (score 9):

Just make sure your query which fetches the comments has `ORDER BY POSTDATE DESC` at the end and the result set will be returned with recent comments at the top. Plus it certainly would be efficient for very large result sets given that *real* databases are really good at this kind of stuff.

Comment: Sanjay has it right.  You want your SQL server to handle the ordering in almost all cases where you care about ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly loop backwards through most `ResultSets`. You should adjust your database queries with an `ORDER BY`.

Usually you can only loop to the next row with `next()`. Depending on the configuration of your connection you may use `last()` for getting the last entry and then retrieve the prior result with `previous()`. However be aware that this usually requires special configuration.

Check the [ResultSet documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). The cursor-type definition is usually vendor dependent.

I'd suggest you try the `ORDER BY` clause in your statement.